# Could not resolve root Entity after upgrading from java 8 to java 17

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

So I had a java 8 project using mysql 5 working totally fine, it uses hibernate as ORM and uses hibernate.cfg.xml mappings for HQL session.createCriteria(...) throughout the project.

I was tasked to upgrade it to java 17 and mysql8, i changed the build.gradle files to use mysql 8 connector and jdk 17, then successfully all errors were removed. Upon running a bunch of errors were thrown depicting that says(one instance of the error):

> Caught exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Category'

On the following piece of code:

```
Category category = (Category) session.createQuery("FROM Category WHERE id= :id ",Category.class)
    .setParameter("id",0)
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .uniqueResult();
```

The above is just a single part where the same error is thrown, its being produced on almost all the queries (Specifically table names & field names).
I have verified the

- Model Classes Names
- fields names
- their types

yet the issue still persisted

Even though i have an entity in my model classes by the exact same name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "settings_categories")
public class Category{
.
..
....
```

I also verified my src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<mapping class="com.xxx.xx.models.settings.Category" />
<mapping class= ..............
so on
```

The error was removed after i used *configuration.addAnnotatedClass()*:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://" + this._host + ":" + this._port + "/" + this._database);
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", this._username);
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", this._password);

configuration.addAnnotatedClass(com.xxx.xx.models.settings.Category.class);
```

but the above approach was not being used previously and the project was working fine plus I have a many tables so adding them like this explicitly doesn't make any sense?

I even connected to the datasbe using this hibernate.cg.xml as a data source in the IDE and alll the tables were retreived fine from it.

Using:

- Hibernate (6.2)
- Gradle (7.3)
- Java 17
- MySQL 8
- IntelliJ Idea Ultimate(Throwing same errors on Eclipse IDE too)

EDIT:
Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">500</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">250</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.check_nullability">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
        
        //All Entity Mapping classes
        
        <mapping class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.TestClass">
        //And the remaining ones
  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
//apply plugin: 'java'


plugins {
    id 'antlr'
}


//allprojects {
//    apply plugin: 'java'
//    group = 'xxx'
//   version = '15.5.8-fromBuildGradle'
//}

//apply plugin: 'application'
//apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    //maven {
    //    url "https://splunk.jfrog.io/splunk/ext-releases-local"
    //}
}

dependencies {
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr:3.5.2"
    implementation 'com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5.4'
    implementation "com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:0.2.3.4"
    implementation "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2"
    
    implementation "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.3"
    implementation "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-parent:2.2"
    implementation "org.apache:apache:13"
    implementation "org.apache:apache:16"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-parent:39"
    implementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"
    implementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:1.3"
    
    implementation "org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA"
    implementation "xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2"
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20230227'

    implementation group: "org.hibernate.orm", name: "hibernate-core", version: "6.2.5.Final"
    implementation group: "mysql", name: "mysql-connector-java", version: "8.0.33"

    implementation group: "com.rabbitmq", name: "amqp-client", version: '4.8.0'
    

    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.9'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.9'
    implementation "com.github.loki4j:loki-logback-appender-jdk8:1.3.2"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13"
}

configurations.all {
    exclude module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "log4j-over-slf4j"
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "jul-to-slf4j"
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-over-log4j"
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "ch.qos.logback.classic.log4j"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j-api"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
}
```

Complete Stack trace:

```
2023-11-01 14:45:05.719 ERROR c.w.e.c.i.d.xxxx:2321 - Caught exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Categor
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:795)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:120)
    at xxxx
    at xxxx
    at xxxx
    at xxxx
    at xxxx
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Category'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1960)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$RootEntityContext.accept(HqlParser.java:2473)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitEntityWithJoins(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1874)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitFromClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1865)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1141)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1818)
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'Category'
```

Comment: Does this maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305823/how-to-configure-hibernate-to-scan-for-entities-in-a-different-module

Comment: @berse2212 I don't think they want to scan for classes, they already added mappings in their `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: Can you please include the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and the `persistence.xml` (if you have one) as well as your `build.gradle` in your post as well as show the full stack trace? I think the error might be due to hibernate 6 using Jakarta EE while previous versions used Java EE. Also, are you using anything starting with `javax.` anywhere in your project (e.g. `javax.persistence.Entity`)?

Comment: @dan1st Edited. And no javax.persistence.Entity was used previously but i changed that to jakarta.persistence.* in all my entity classes

Comment: In your `hibernate.cfg.xml`, you have `<mapping class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Test.class>`. Is this missing an `"` or is it just a typo in your edit? Also, is there really a `.class` at the end or is that just for demonstration?

Comment: no no that was a typo, also there's no .class it was just for demonstration